# unable insert record when database object is called from another class

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-context

First of all I am new to android and Java.

I am developing a android application where I wrote separate classes for `database` and `tables` inside the `database`, Now I want to make a insertion in to the table from total different class by creating the objects to database class and table class.

I am getting below errors in log file don't understand what they exactly mean.

```
01-27 15:15:42.283: D/libEGL(17506): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_genymotion.so
01-27 15:15:42.287: D/(17506): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb891b390, tid 17506
01-27 15:15:42.363: D/libEGL(17506): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_genymotion.so
01-27 15:15:42.367: D/libEGL(17506): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_genymotion.so
01-27 15:15:42.743: W/EGL_genymotion(17506): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
01-27 15:15:42.767: E/OpenGLRenderer(17506): Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache
01-27 15:15:42.823: E/OpenGLRenderer(17506): Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from Caches::initConstraints()
01-27 15:15:42.827: D/OpenGLRenderer(17506): Enabling debug mode 0
01-27 15:15:45.567: I/Choreographer(17506): Skipped 39 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
01-27 15:15:45.831: D/AndroidRuntime(17506): Shutting down VM
01-27 15:15:45.855: W/dalvikvm(17506): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4b8c648)
01-27 15:15:45.943: E/AndroidRuntime(17506): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-27 15:15:45.943: E/AndroidRuntime(17506): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.portfoliomanager/com.example.portfoliomanager.stockmanager}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-27 15:15:45.943: E/AndroidRuntime(17506):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2137)
01-27 15:15:45.943: E/AndroidRuntime(17506):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
01-27 15:15:45.943: E/AndroidRuntime(17506):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
01-27 15:15:45.943: E/AndroidRuntime(17506):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
01-27 15:15:45.943: E/AndroidRuntime(17506):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-27 15:15:45.943: E/AndroidRuntime(17506):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-27 15:15:45.943: E/AndroidRuntime(17506):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
01-27 15:15:45.943: E/AndroidRuntime(17506):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-27 15:15:45.943: E/AndroidRuntime(17506):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
01-27 15:15:45.943: E/AndroidRuntime(17506):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
01-27 15:15:45.943: E/AndroidRuntime(17506):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
01-27 15:15:45.943: E/AndroidRuntime(17506):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-27 15:15:45.943: E/AndroidRuntime(17506): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-27 15:15:45.943: E/AndroidRuntime(17506):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:235)
01-27 15:15:45.943: E/AndroidRuntime(17506):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:224)
01-27 15:15:45.943: E/AndroidRuntime(17506):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
01-27 15:15:45.943: E/AndroidRuntime(17506):    at com.example.portfoliomanager.Database.<init>(Database.java:17)
01-27 15:15:45.943: E/AndroidRuntime(17506):    at com.example.portfoliomanager.stockmanager.<init>(stockmanager.java:14)
01-27 15:15:45.943: E/AndroidRuntime(17506):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
01-27 15:15:45.943: E/AndroidRuntime(17506):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1130)
01-27 15:15:45.943: E/AndroidRuntime(17506):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
01-27 15:15:45.943: E/AndroidRuntime(17506):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2128)
01-27 15:15:45.943: E/AndroidRuntime(17506):    ... 11 more
0
```

Below is my code.

Database Class

```
public class Database extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    private static  String dbname="Manager";
    private static int dbversion=2;
    SQLiteDatabase db;

    public Database(Context context) {

        super(context, dbname, null, dbversion);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        StockTable st=new StockTable();
        db.execSQL(st.stocktable);
        }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

activity class from where database is called.

```
public class stockmanager extends Activity{

    String getentry=null;
    Database d=new Database(this);
    StockTable st=new StockTable();


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.stockmanager);

    final Button AddStock=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        final EditText entry=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        final Button BroDetail=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

        AddStock.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                getentry=entry.getText().toString();
                d.db.insert(st.tablename, null,st.insert());


            }
        });
                }
}
```

Finally table creation class.

```
public class StockTable {

final String tablename="StockTable";
private String column1="Stock_ID";
private String column2="StockName";

stockmanager sm=new stockmanager();

final String stocktable = "CREATE TABLE " + tablename + 
            " (" + column1+ " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY , " + column2 + " TEXT) ";

public ContentValues insert(){

    ContentValues cvi=new ContentValues();
    for(int i=0;i<=sm.getentry.length();i++)
    {
        cvi.put(column1, 1);
        cvi.put(column2,sm.getentry);
                    }

    return cvi;
}

public void delete(){


}

}
```

Please help me to solve this as I was stuck for a few hours.

Comment: you can publish the layout xml file?

Comment: yes but I can explain layout has just on text field and buttion when data is entered in text and button is pressed a record need to be inserted that is the functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have other problems, but here is what it is now:

```
Database d=new Database(this);
```

You initialize "d" before "this" has constructed. Move the initializer to onCreate like this:

```
d=new Database(this);
```

And in your StockTable class you are making a reference to your activity before it is initialized also ("stockmanager" does not exist and has no reference);

You should probably look at a couple tutorials on the DB creation and use process. Here is one: http://hmkcode.com/android-simple-sqlite-database-tutorial/

and another: http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/database/sqlite/sqlitedatabase/android-sqlite-example/

Comment: I didn't get `stockmanager has no reference` can you explain more.

Comment: in StockTable - this line: stockmanager sm=new stockmanager();

Comment: oh what needs to be done there? Please bare with me I am new to android... what is the correct way of doing it?

Comment: You cano't create Activity Instance!! you need create StockTable at your activity and refrence the activity to this class. Activity is  like "thread" in android and not as Object.